# iOS Support ad vs ad-free versions of same app

Tags: ios, xcode, iad, ads

I have a paid app on appstore that is not returning much revenue.
So I have made a new version that is free instead, but it includes ads.
Now two questions.

1) I want to make an alert "If you want ad-free version press here". Here the user will be informed of the cost (1dollar) and then they can "register" and get adfree version. Now the million dollar question is: is that done using an "inApp purchase"?

2) How do I "justify" for the users who have bought the app before? now it is free maybe if they contact me I can "register" them in the inApp??

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
1) How do i check inside my app code if user has bought "inApp purchase"?
2) Does anybody know a way to check if a user is an "old user that has paid before app became with ads"?

Comment: Yes, it would be done through an In-App purchase. For the users who have bought the app, thats a hard one, you can probably try to write some code that detects which app it is (the free or paid) and automatically remove the ads

Comment: Good point. And for the which app it is, i can check the version of the app! :)

Comment: Actually that wont work because the old ppl have already updated and they will have same version all of them. Need to rethink it :) I dont think there is any way to check which app the customer downloaded first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers:
1) adfree version should be managed via an inApp Purchase and managed via StoreKit (Apple SDK hosting) or different hosting of your choice (online server).
2) To preserve "old" customers, you should make an update (still paid and with no ads), where you add a plist file and copy it to the "Documents" folder, and wait a couple of monthes after release. That should give the paid users a chance to update. After that you release a free version with ads, and only add the ads if the plist does not exist. This will help you in 95% of the cases.
PS: the 5% resting cases is if the customer chooses to delete the app all together and download it again.

Hope that helps other peeps with the same problem :)

Answer (score 5):

It's really quite simple.

If you have two apps (a free, ad-supported app and a "PRO" ad-free app) then you just encourage the users of the free app to upgrade to the paid-for app, with a link to the paid-for app's iTunes App Store location.

If you have just one app, then you use in-app purchasing to hide the ads.

HOWEVER, if you have just one app, that was once paid-for and ad-free, which you have changed to being free but ad-supported, all the existing customers that paid for the app are now seeing the ads (assuming they have upgraded) and there is no practical way to give then the ad-free version back, without them paying.

UNLESS, you planned this in advance, and left a little code behind with the final paid-for, ad-free version that said "mark me as paid" (although even that probably wouldn't survive a reinstall or a cross-device install).

Comment: The two apps solution is not a good one. At least not for my app. But I guess they will just have to accept the ads. I can't seem to figure out a way to differentiate :(